# Error while accessing the $httpProvider.defaults.headers configuration object in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to overwrite header defaults for POST requests in http header. Even i am providing $httpProvider in the function argument, but still it is throwing error.

Code is -

```
 angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngCookies'])
.service('sharedProperties', function ($cookieStore, $http, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-                              form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

 });
```

The error is -

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider <- sharedProperties**

Answer (score 13):

$httpProvider is accessible only in config... you should change you code like:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngCookies'])
.config(function($httpProvider){
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
})
.service('sharedProperties', function ($cookieStore, $http) {

});
```

Comment: Finally, a straight answer! Still using angularjs 1.x in 2020... Thanks :)